# iphone & notifications : max number of notifications?

Tags: iphone, notifications, apple-push-notifications

I have an iPhone app sending notifications and everything is working fine... Except sometimes :)

Let me explain : I'm using a pretty simple PHP script to send the notifications (using the `stream_context_create` method) but some users told me they do not receive some notifications. Apparently, I may encounter some cases where I need to send up to 50,000 notifications within a minute and I think this might be the problem. I'm using one single stream to send all the notifications.

Did any of you guys encountered such an issue? Do I need to split in several streams? Is there any info about the max number of notifications I may send in a stream?

Thanks :)

**Edit 1**

"Speed" is not the issue here : I am able to push all my notifications to Apple within a minute  (I may have some issues in the future if my number of users growns but it's OK ATM). The problem I see here is that Apple may consider me a spammer or something and does not deliver all my 50,000 notifications :/ Do you guys have any idea how I can get sure about that?

Comment: Have you considered creating a daemon script and pushing notifications onto a stack which the daemon handles at an appropriate pace? If your notifications can arrive a one-five minutes late, I think this is an appropriate solution without completely changing language/etc.

Comment: Just edited my post, I realized my question wasn't really accurate

Comment: Well, I know we had the same problems with apns. I think we solved it by using a queue and only sending a capped amount of notifications per seconds to Apple. I don't exactly know what this cap is but you might want to look into this and experiment a little.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I asked an Apple developer representative about this and was told there were no rate limits and that the system had never dropped a notification.

(This was 12 months ago, when Push was still relatively new, so they may have changed policies since then)

Comment: Just a comment : when sending the stream content to Apple, whenever an invalide token is detected, the connection is stopped. So make sure whenever you send your data that the fwrite() was successful.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather develop the code to send the notifications in C. PHP, being a scripting language, can not (probably) guarantee the required speed to handle 50K notifications per minute. Moreover, you may need a very hugely provisioned server with latest generation CPUs and a lot of memory. Indeed, to meet the QOS you require, you must be able to send about 14 notification per second. I doubt PHP is actually able to cope with this rate.

In the past I had my own provider, and my QOS was much less than the one you require. Then I decided to switch to a commercial service provider, Urban Airship. I have found this service works like a charm. None of the users have - ever - reported a missing notification. You have to pay for it, but handling this stuff by yourself may prove to be an incredible hassle.

Comment: Just edited my post, I realized my question wasn't really accurate

Answer (score 0):

If there is a failure in the notification stream (i.e. bad token), then a few tokens proceeding it are missed.  This has been my experience, so I send one token at a time.  No more failures, other than the one bad token.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into exactly the same issue, but with far fewer pushes per stream. In my case, I pushed all my messages, about 250, on the same stream, and none would be delivered. It does appear that a bad token seems to cause the failure, but so far I'm not certain what constitutes a bad token.

I've read elsewhere that pushing messages using the distribution tokens in a sandbox environment and pushing messages using sandbox tokens in the distribution environment can cause a stream to fail, but I've mixed tokens in both environment and haven't missed messages, but I was only pushing a few messages in one stream at the time.

Long story short: I'm pushing one message per stream, and it works fine. It takes on the order of seconds to push 250 messages, which seems terribly inefficient, but its just a minor nuisance to me.